# Express-Server receives wrong data from MYSQL-database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, express

I am using express with an mySQL database and I want to retrieve data with an select statement.

```
connection.query('select * from table1', function(err, rows, fields){console.log(rows)}
```

The columns in the database looks like this:

```
id, name, producer
```

The id in the database is:

```
100000001200000001
```

In the console.log I recieve:

```
{id: 10000000120000000, name: "Tim", producer: "Tims"}
```

As you can see, the "1" is lost in the JSON Object.

I don't have any clue about what the problem could be...

Comment: it is bigint in the database...

Answer (score 0):

Your integer is upper the `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` in Javascript.
You should use `BigInt(int)` to get it correctly.

You definitely want to check this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt.

Comment: Thanks but I can't get the "1" with transforming it afterwords to BigInt.

Comment: You cannot have it as a number (BigInt will put an n at the end) but you can have it as a string. For example doing: `id: '' + BigInt(100000001200000001)`